# Getting a .co.uk domain that is already registered

Tags: domains, domain-registration

There is a .co.uk name that I want (I've had the .com version for nearly 7 years now).

I would even be prepared to pay a small amount for it, but on http://whois.domaintools.com/ only a business name is shown (DOTCOMBIZ-AU) and an Australian address. There is no email address or telephone number.

It is also interesting to note that "Registrant type: Non-UK Individual". I was under the impression that for a .co.uk you had to be UK based (which I and my business - if you could call it that - are).

Also note that nothing is hosted on the domain, browsers simply return a page not found.

Is there anything I can do to try and obtain this domain? Or is there at least any way to contact the owner?

Thank you for your help.

Jonathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first step would be to contact the current registrant. If you feel that they have breached Nominet's terms for use of a UK domain, then you can use the [dispute resolution service](http://www.nic.uk/disputes/drs/) to settle issues over ownership of the domain. The Nominet site is uite good, and even explains [rights over domains](http://www.nic.uk/disputes/drs/rights/) too

Comment: I think this is classed as domain parking. This would be against Nominet's terms of service.

Comment: in that case call the Nominet and say "hey, what the hell?"

Comment: Thank you for the advice, and for providing a link to correct website :)

Answer (score 1):

Contact the DOTCOMBIZ-AU guys (look them up, and attempt to get to them), than make your offer?

Comment: I have attempted to find out their details, but the only contact details I have been able to work out is the Australian address they supplied on Whois. I think I may have a name for them, but it is impossible to tell.